# Xcode -- moving a variable and associated property from one class to another

Tags: xcode, refactoring

I find myself doing this pretty often.  Currently I am cut/pasting the variable declaration, the property, the @synthesize, and usually also the release call in the dealloc method.  That's four copy and pastes.  Is there an easy way to do all of that at once.

Answer (score 0):

There's not an automated to do this per se, however this article by Matt Gallagher has a user script you can use to add the `@property`, `@synthesize`, and `-release` lines from a given ivar. This should alleviate some of your pain.

http://cocoawithlove.com/2008/12/instance-variable-to-synthesized.html